# Does the following program execute the nested loop on the first iteration of the outer loop?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

On the first iteration of the nested loop `i = 2` and `j = 2`. However, the condition for the nested loop is `j < i`. Does this mean that the nested loop is not executed? What is happening?

```js
showPrimes(10);

function showPrimes(n) {
    nextPrime:

    for (let i = 2; i < n; i++) {
        for (let j = 2; j < i; j++)
            if (i % j == 0) continue nextPrime;
        console.log(i); // a prime number
    }
}
```

Comment: What this purpose of this nested loop. It doesnot `alert` primes numbers.

Comment: The nested loop doesn't have any effect...

Comment: function showPrimes(n) {
  nextPrime: for (let i = 2; i < n; i++) {

    for (let j = 2; j < i; j++) {
      if (i % j == 0) continue nextPrime;
    }

    alert( i ); // a prime
  }
}

Comment: What's the use of the ```continue;``` statement?

Comment: It's not true on the first iteration. Hence, `2` is a prime number.

Comment: continue helps to stop the current iteration and starts next one

Comment: the code is working perfectly and showing prime numbers

Comment: @MaheerAli will u please explain me how this code is flowing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok lets explain this nested loop in steps:

1. Initially `i=2` and `j=2` so the outer loop will execute but the **nested loop won't execute**. skipping inner loop it prints `2` which is at end of main loop `console.log(i)`
2. The loops ends and `i = 3`. this time `j < i` is `true` so nested loop starts.
3. During first nested loop `i = 3` and `j = 2`
4. the `continue` won't execute `i % j` is not `0` so it end and `j` increases. Now `i=3` and `j=3` and nested loop exits and prints `3`
5. Now the `i=4` and nested loop will be executed because `j=2` and `j<i`.
6. The condition `i % j` is `true`. So this time `continue nextPrime` will executed and the outer loop will start again with `i = 5`.
7. Now `i = 5` so nested loop will be executed. The values of `j` will be `2` `3` `4` in nested loops. None of them will cause `continue` because `5%2` `5%3` or `5%4` is not `0`.
8. Nested loop will exit after `j` becomes `5`. And it will print `i` which is `5`.

   `continue nextPrime` does everything. It will check if `i % j == 0` it means `i` is not prime. So it will jump back to the outer loop with `i = i + 1` and will not go the last to `console.log()`

```js
showPrimes(6);

function showPrimes(n) {
    nextPrime:
    for (let i = 2; i < n; i++) {
        for (let j = 2; j < i; j++){
            console.log(`i:${i} j:${j}`)
            if (i % j == 0) continue nextPrime;
        }
        console.log(`prime${i}`); // a prime number
    }
}
```

**Why `j` is changed again and again**

Because its a local variable and its always initialized to `2`. Its not only limited to the inner loop. When the inner loop is ended it get destroyed and in the during next loop it again gets initialized to `2` due to `for (let j = 2; ...`

Comment: thanks for explanation as you said in 4th step j value is 3 and again in 5th step j value became 2 how this happens?

Comment: @Raghuram I have added an explanation

Comment: @Raghuram `i` is local to the outer for loop. As outer `for` loop is not ended so its value doesnot change like `j`. But `j` is local to the inner loop. Inner loop is created several time so the value of `j` get destroyed and initialized to `2` every time inner loop is started.

Comment: thanks man i am new to js it seems there's a lot to learn , at last i understood it

Answer (score 2):

Here's a chart detailing the flow of your program:

```
+---+---+-------------------------------------------------------------+
| i | j |                            Notes                            |
+---+---+-------------------------------------------------------------+
| 2 | 2 | Nested loop condition is false. Hence, 2 is a prime number. |
| 3 | 2 | 3 is not divisible by 2. Let's keep searching.              |
| 3 | 3 | Nested loop condition is false. Hence, 3 is a prime number. |
| 4 | 2 | 4 is divisible by 2. Hence, it's not a prime number.        |
| 5 | 2 | 5 is not divisible by 2. Let's keep searching.              |
| 5 | 3 | 5 is not divisible by 3. Let's keep searching.              |
| 5 | 4 | 5 is not divisible by 4. Let's keep searching.              |
| 5 | 5 | Nested loop condition is false. Hence, 5 is a prime number. |
| 6 | 2 | 6 is divisible by 2. Hence, it's not a prime number.        |
| 7 | 2 | 7 is not divisible by 2. Let's keep searching.              |
| 7 | 3 | 7 is not divisible by 3. Let's keep searching.              |
| 7 | 4 | 7 is not divisible by 4. Let's keep searching.              |
| 7 | 5 | 7 is not divisible by 5. Let's keep searching.              |
| 7 | 6 | 7 is not divisible by 6. Let's keep searching.              |
| 7 | 7 | Nested loop condition is false. Hence, 7 is a prime number. |
| 8 | 2 | 8 is divisible by 2. Hence, it's not a prime number.        |
| 9 | 2 | 9 is not divisible by 2. Let's keep searching.              |
| 9 | 3 | 9 is divisible by 3. Hence, it's not a prime number.        |
+---+---+-------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Hopefully, that explains why the program works even though the nested loop doesn't execute when `i = 2` and `j = 2`.

Comment: thanks but what i am not understanding is i value is increasing from start cause i++ , how come j value is falling back to 2 after few iteration.

Comment: That's because you explicitly set `j = 2` at the beginning of each iteration of the outer loop.

Answer (score 0):

If prime should return true for primes, false for non-primes, then when you detect a non-prime, simply return false. As the comments point out, you don't need two loops to do that. You can simply loop from 2 to n-1, attempting to divide without a remainder.

Comment: This does not answer the OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

The nested loop is not executed in the first iteration of the outer loop, i.e. when `i == 2`. In the second iteration of the outer loop we have `i == 3`, hence the nested loop condition now reads `j < 3`, so that it es evaluated once with the value `j == 2`. For the third iteration of the outer loop we have `i == 4`, so that the nested loop is evaluated twice for the values 2 and 3. And so on.

Hope it helps - Carlos